# Thematic Graduated Bar Chart from polyline

Tags: thematic-map

I have a road broken into 10m sections, each section has a road condition score, I was hoping to create a bar coming of each section based on that condition and also color them based on a categories e.g 1-40 Green, 40-80 Amber, 80+ Red.

It's kind of like graduated lines but I don't want to change the thickness of the actual line, I would like for them to grow perpendicular to the line e.g

[image]

In this image each color is 10m section of road and the grey is the road. I feel this may not work well on actual road as roads curve and the height changes maybe lost but I would still like to pose the questions as it could be an inserting way of showing data along a linear feature.